# Read only fields validation in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, required

I want to display some dynamic data for that if field is empty I want to show "ABC is required" on load of page it self .

How do I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd write your validations as you normally would with the following added to the end of your validation expressions. `|| formName.$pristine`

This will trigger the validations on page load.

Comment: I am writing my application as single page application . Where i dont use form . is there any way to trigger without formName

Comment: It's best practise to use form when validating inputs, afterall an `input` should belong to a `form` anyway.

Comment: Could you please provide some code snippet how to trigger validation and show particular error messages if incoming field value is empty?